# Not able to stimulate change on Input in a modal: React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react-redux application where I have a component rendering a button which opens a modal when clicked.

**Component:**

```
class ModalComp extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    visible: false,
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
  };
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  };
  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal} />
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          style={{ top: 53 }}
          confirmLoading={confirmLoading}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          footer={null}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Title"
            autosize
            value={title}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalComp;
```

**test cases:**

```
it('allows user to enter text in Title input when the modal is open', () => {
  component = mount(<ModalComp />);
  const button = component.find(Button);
  button.simulate('click');
  component.update();
  const title = 'newtitle';
  const TitleInput = component.find(Input);
  TitleInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: title } });
  component.update();
  expect(TitleInput.props().value).toEqual(title);
});
```

I am able to find the nodes correctly but the value is remaining an empty string `""` only. I think the problem might be with simulating the change event
As the title value is not updating at all. Do I need to do anything more? How can I update the DOM text value?

Comment: `visible={visible}` shouldn't it be `visible={this.state.visible}`?

Comment: that was a typo while putting the minimal code. My main question is in testing part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not with the `change` simulation but with the instance of input used in the `expect` changing test case to like this did the trick.

**testcase:**

```
it('allows user to enter text in Title input when the modal is open', () => {
component = mount(<ModalComp />)
const button = component.find(Button)
button.simulate('click')
component.update()
const title = "newtitle"
const TitleInput = component.find(Input)
TitleInput.simulate('change', {target: {value: title}})
component.update()
//change in below expect statement in finding the input rather than using the 
//previous one will do the trick
expect(component.find(Input).props().value).toEqual(title)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the rep to add a comment so this'll have to do. Please refer to this https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76 it's a known bug. Some of the ways they have tried to fix the issue is 
Setting the target value

```
TitleInput.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Test'}});
```

setting the node value

```
TitleInput.node.value = 'Test';
```

by simulating multiple keypresses

```
TitleInput.simulate('keydown', {keyCode: 13, target: {value:'Test'}});
```

or by using the onChangeText event instead

```
TitleInput.simulate('onChangeText', 'Text')
```

Comment: none of these seems to work in my case first one is what i have tried doing second one is giving me an error as `use react element istead` third and 4th are also showing no effect

Comment: actually what iam doing was correct expect some part of `expect` statement in `expect` statement i was using the instance of the component which is the one i got before simulating so it was returning empty string "". thanks for your help though